# Insert into a Binary SearchTree that impliments Generics

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to create a binary search tree that impliments generics. i am struggling with inserting nodes after i have inserted the Root of the tree, it is most likely my insertion logic that is wrong. but i can not see how.

My question is, what is wrong with my insertion logic because i can not get any nodes inserted after the root.

this is my insert function

```
public Node<T> insert(Node<T> node, T data) {
    if (node == null)
    {  System.out.println("1");
        return new Node<T>(data);
    }
    if (node.getData().compareTo(data) < 0) {
        node = new Node<T>(data, insert(node.getLeft(), data),node.getRight());
         System.out.println("2");
        node.setLeft(insert(node.getLeft(), data));
    } else if (node.getData().compareTo(data) > 0) {

         System.out.println("3");
        node = new Node<T>(data, node.getLeft(), insert(node.getRight(), data));
        node.setRight(insert(node.getRight(), data));
    }
    // After insert the new node, check and rebalance the current node if
    // necessary.
    switch (balanceNumber(node)) {
        case 1:
            node = rotateLeft(node);
            break;
        case -1:
            node = rotateRight(node);
            break;
        default:
            return node;
    }
    return node;
}
```

and this is where i impliment it

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    double x = Double.parseDouble(txtXCoord.getText());
    double y = Double.parseDouble(txtYCoord.getText());
    double m = Double.parseDouble(txtMass.getText());
    String name = txtInput.getText();

    switch(e.getActionCommand()){
    case "add":
        try {
            tree.insert( drawPanel.tree.getRoot(), new Body(x,y,m,name));
            drawPanel.setTree(tree);
            //drawPanel.paint(getGraphics());
            drawPanel.setVisible(true);
            tree.PrintTree();


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
```

i should mention that i have a function that prints the tree.

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem? Does the code not compile? Does it throw some `Exception`? Please be more specific.

Comment: My question is, what is wrong with my insertion logic because i can not get any nodes inserted after the root.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: Okay, sorry, I'm a n00b and in a rush. ill make the question better

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work after you remove the following two lines:

`node = new Node<T>(data, insert(node.getLeft(), data),node.getRight());`


`node = new Node<T>(data, node.getLeft(), insert(node.getRight(), data));`

You need also the handle the case when `node.getData().compareTo(data) == 0`. In that case, you will update the actual data of the node.